# How to change LAN address range with Motorola SBG900E?

Tags: lan, home-networking, ip-address

I'm trying to get work VPN properly working from home (problem is, when it's enabled, I can access the private network but not public internet). A colleague suggested I should try **changing my home LAN address space from the default 192.168.0.X to 10.0.0.0/8**.

How would I go about doing that? I'm connected to the internet through a cable modem (also a wifi access point) whose exact model is Motorola SBG900E Wireless SURFboard Gateway.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browse to http://192.168.0.1/ (on a computer connected to the LAN) to access the cable modem admin tools.

The default username is **admin** and password **motorola**. (If you have changed and then forgotten the password, press reset for 30 seconds—the reset "button" is the tiny pin hole at the top of the back plate—after which the default credentials should work again.)

Once logged in, go to **Gateway** -> **LAN** -> **DHCP Server Config**. You should see something like this:

[image]

Now, set **LAN IP Address** to 10.0.0.1, and **Starting IP Address** to 10.0.0.2

Click Apply, and that's it! For the change to take effect, you still need to renew DHCP lease on each client computer so that they get a 10.0.0.X IP address.

Remember that after this change, the cable modem admin page will be available at http://10.0.0.1/

In my case, this indeed helped with the VPN problem: now when VPN connection is on, I can access both the private network and public internet.